# Is PHP 5.5.3 on Ubuntu 13.10 secure?

Tags: ubuntu, php

I'm looking into using Ubuntu 13.10 server, but was noticing the apt-get PHP version that installs is 5.5.3, when PHP 5.5.9 is the most current version according to php.net. I'm wondering if I can trust 5.5.3 to be secure or if there is a trusted way to keep PHP more current.

Answer (score 3):

Only you can decide and to do so you have a bit of work to do. You'll have to track down all of the security related bugs in the [change log](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) and then check to see if they have been backported into the 5.5.3 provided on Ubuntu 13.10. You can find the Ubuntu Security Notices [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/saucy/).

For example [USN-2055-1](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2055-1/) is a security related bug that was fixed in php 5.5.7 but as you can see from the USN it has been backported into all of the currently supported Ubuntu versions.

Comment: How trust worthy are the PPAs (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas)?

Comment: @Brent: I've no idea - perhaps you should ask on http://askubuntu.com or their chat.

Comment: Good thought ... I'm not sure why I forgot about askubuntu.com. :)